# Using table variables in Oracle Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have lots of experience with T-SQL (MS SQL Server).

There it is quite common to first select some set of records into a
table variable or say temp table `t`, and then work with this `t`
throughout the whole SP body using it just like a regular table 
(for JOINS, sub-queries, etc.).

Now I am trying the same thing in Oracle but it's a pain.
I get errors all the way and it keeps saying
that it does not recognize my table (i.e. my table variable).

```
Error(28,7): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Error(30,28): PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

I start thinking what at all is possible to do with this 
table variable and what not (in the SP body) ?

I have this declaration:

```
TYPE V_CAMPAIGN_TYPE IS TABLE OF V_CAMPAIGN%ROWTYPE; 
tc V_CAMPAIGN_TYPE;
```

What on Earth can I do with this `tc` now in my SP?!

This is what I am trying to do in the body of the SP.

```
  UPDATE ( SELECT t1.STATUS_ID, t2.CAMPAIGN_ID
            FROM V_CAMPAIGN t1
            INNER JOIN tc t2 ON t1.CAMPAIGN_ID = t2.CAMPAIGN_ID
            ) z
  SET z.STATUS_ID = 4;
```

`V_CAMPAIGN` is a DB view, `tc` is my table variable

Comment: Please post full code. You could use http://dbfiddle.uk

Comment: The `table of` syntax is perhaps misleading. `tc` in your example is not a table, it's a collection. Typically this type of construction is replaced with a `with` clause or else a global temporary table in Oracle.

Comment: You could always use something that Oracle supports, like temporary tables.

Comment: In Oracle you typically don't even use temporary tables. You simply operate on the real ones. Just join to the table you would have used to populate the "table variable"

Comment: Maybe you should take a step back and describe the underlying problem you are trying to solve, rather then finding a way to apply SQL Server approaches to Oracle

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name But the whole point of using a table variable (or say temp table) is to select just a subset of all rows, and then use them. Also when I join to this table variable / temp table it serves as a filter. I may have 1 million rows in my real table but may be interested in just working with 1000 of these records. Another useful purpose is to write this select statement (which gives me the table var / temp table) only  once and not many times in the body of the SP.

Comment: This is impossible to answer without seeing the real problem. In Oracle it's typically faster to just select the data you want to work with by applying a filter (e.g. inside a sub-select) instead of copying data back and forth from a table to a temporary table. As there is no concept of "table variables" there is no point in trying to emulate it.

Comment: `UPDATE V_CAMPAIGN 
    SET STATUS_ID = 4
    WHERE CAMPAIGN_ID IN (SELECT CAMPAIGN_ID FROM TABLE(tc));`

Answer (score 2):

Presumably you are trying to update a subset of the V_CAMPAIGN records.
While in SQLServer it may be useful to define a 'temporary' table containing the subset and then operate on that it isn't necessary in Oracle.
Simply update the table with the where clause you would have used to define the temp table.
E.g.

```
UPDATE v_campaign z
   SET z.status_id = 4
 WHERE z.column_name = 'a value'
   AND z.status <> 4
```

I assume that the technique you are familiar with is to minimise the effect of read locks that are taken while selecting the data.
Oracle uses a different locking strategy so the technique is mostly unnecessary.

Echoing a comment above - tell us what you want to achieve in Oracle and you will get suggestions for the best way forward.